# Festival CentOS 7 without Asterisk, Latin Spanish

Tags: centos, festival, voice

Only I want to install a Spanish Latin voice for Festival, then I was looking for them.

I'm using CentOS, but I can't find the TTS packages...

I'm not Expert in this matter.
I was looking for using google, but the information I found is Ubuntu and .deb extension files. Other based on Asterisk and FestBox... RPM

My question are:

- Is FestVox needed?
- Is Asterisk needed?
- Where I can get Latin Spanish voices, please links...
- Have you step by step installation of this voices?

Is it possible to use another TTS (Loquendo, aCapela, etc) On Festival, are they interchangeable?

Thank you!

Comment: The post is a bit confusing. I dealt with voices for an asterisk package, and got the clear impression there is a wide array of choices for voices...but they are paid. There are also some extra packages, however I done it a while ago, and cannot recall the specific details.

Comment: You have reason... I want only latin Spanish voice for Festival...  I mixed Asterisk... Sorry..